# Sub-routines in PDP-11 assembly

Tags: assembly

So I'm writing a program is assembly , and I'm trying to use sub-routines, but I have a problem.
I'v written a routine that resembles a switch case . It reads an input , and based on it's value , it writes to a reserved address in the stack the address of the following sub-routine.

It looks something like this:

```
1000    jsr r5,switchcase
    // let the return address be 1004
1004    jsr r5,@0(sp)
```

the first jsr goes to the switch case, which writes to the first address in the stack.
the second one jumps to that address.

I'm using a simulator , and every time it reaches that line it  simply stops. I don't know what goes wrong :/

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you accounting for the fact that the `jsr` pushes the return value on the stack, thus changing the offset you need to use?

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Actually, jsr r5,... pushes r5 onto the stack, and then assigns the current PC to r5.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `jsr r5,@0(sp)` pushes the old `r5` onto the stack and puts the current `R7` (PC) into `r5`. Therefore your program does not jump to the address on the stack, but to the address stored in `r5`, wharever this is.
So in your example the 1st `jsr` instruction writes `r5` onto the stack, and then assigns `1004` to `r5`.
EDIT:  When the program returns with `rts`, it restores the old value of `r5` from the stack.
The 2nd `jsr` instruction pushes thus again this value onto the stack, and then jumps to this address, since it is on top of the stack (distance 0).
If the subroutine called with the 1st `jsr` indeed leaves a subroutine address on top of the stack, and the 2nd `jsr` should jump there, one had to use `jsr r5,@2(sp)` instead. But I would consider this as everything else than good programming style.
Hope I got it right this time...

Comment: But wouldn't the second jsr also write 1008 into r5?  Also, the return from the first subroutine should fix up the stack.

Comment: @JeremyP: You are completely right, thanks for pointing this out. Sorry, I did PDP11 programming 30 years ago... I will edit my answer to correct it.